# Indication for camera loading in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i use the custom camera in my application , while launching the camera it will take some time to load the camera, at that time the seems to be idle , i need to show some indication or some animation while the camera will take some time to launch. Any one suggest some idea .

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you launch the intent your app doesn't have the focus anymore, there's nothing that you can do while waiting. Your best best is to popup a toaster or a dialog box just before stating something like : "Please wait while launching the photo app".

A toaster should do the trick.